# How to create a hasMany relationship with different models in folder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a strange Laravel 9 setup due to being constrained to a very ancient database.

I'm trying to come up with a clean way to create a hasMany relationship to multiple models located in a folder. I believe it would be easiest explained with diagrams:

```
app/Models/
- Customer
app/Models/Records/
- Orange
- Green
- Blue
```

Now, all of these records has some connection to customer, but these are all different as well, for example, orange refers to customer using `cid`, where Green might use `customerid`.

I've already set up logic where every record model has a customer belongsTo relationship depending on the different field names.

```
public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer', 'CustomerId');
    }
```

I need to create a `records()` function in the Customer model, that pulls in all of these Records where found. I can't create any new tables that would be stored on the DB.

Comment: Show the content of all your relevant models.

Comment: The models all have a customerId field, and then details about the color, and those detail columns are all different as well. The only relevant field they all contain is some link to the customer.

Comment: You will have to manually define the relationship on _Orange_ using `belongsTo(\App\Models\Customer::class, 'cid');` and the inverse in _Customer_ would be `hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Orange::class)`.

Comment: So I'd just do multiple hasMany's and merge them or return them in an array? I figured that was the solution... bummer but it is what it is :)

Comment: you might try using migration + seeder to add extra field into lets say Green so it will have field cid with content of customerid , by the way is each of these Orange Green  Blue models has different table name ?

Comment: @Win yeah, Orange is called... "OrangeRecord", green is called "GreenRecord" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these solutions quite achieved what I was looking for in terms of simplicity, and in my case my database is quite out of date and slow, so I ended up landing on a solution that is quite simple and faster than everything posted for my use case:

```php
public function records()
{
  return [
      "Orange" => $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Orange::class, 'CustomerId', 'Id')->get(),
      "Blue" => $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Blue::class, 'Customerid', 'Id')->get(),
      "Purple" => $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Purple::class, 'customerid', 'Id')->get(),
      "Black" => $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Black::class, 'CustomerId', 'Id')->get(),
      "Green" => $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Green::class, 'Customerid', 'Id')->get(),
      "Cyan" => $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Records\Cyan::class, 'CustomerId', 'Id')->get()
    ];
}
```

This achieves what I was looking for in terms of setting up the relationships when the customerId field was subject to change on the other tables, and is pretty readable overall.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple tables (models) to be connected as hasMany is probably not possible out of the box in Laravel.

However if you do really need to combine them all, I did once but it is not pretty.

First add following to each of your App\Records\Model in example is Green

```
class Green extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'GreenRecords';

   ....
   ....

   // this is to append/add extra fields into your model
   // that not exist inside the table it self
   protected $appends = [
        'product_data',
        'stuffs',
   ];

   // relationship to App\Models\Customer
   public function customer()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customerid', 'id');
   }

   // you can use it later as Green::query()->customer($id)->get()
   public function scopeCustomer($query, $id)
   {
        return $query->where('customerid', $id);
   }
   
   // you can add here as many data as you like from table GreenRecords, 
   // this will make Green Orange and Blue as if they have common fields
   // you can also separate them by adding add each custom field to $appends
   public function getProductDataAttribute()
   {
        return [
           'name' => $this->name,
           'color' => $this->color,
           'stuffs' => $this->stuffs,
           'other_stuffs' => $this->other_stuffs,
        ];
   }
   public function getStuffsAttribute()
   {
        return $this->stuffs;
   }
   
}
```

And now for the Customer model

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    // your Customer relation to Orange
    public function oranges()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Orange::class, 'cid', 'id');
    }

    // your Customer relation to Green
    public function greens()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Green::class, 'customerid', 'id');
    }

    public function getRecords(): Collection
    {
       // we can not use collection merge due to same 'id' in Orange and Green
       $collections = collect();

       if ($oranges = Orange::query()
           ->customer($this->id)
           ->get()
       ) {
           foreach ($oranges as $record) {
               $collections->push($record);
           }
       }

       if ($greens = Green::query()
           ->customer($this->id)
           ->get()
        ) {
           foreach ($greens as $record) {
               $collections->push($record);
           }
       }

       return $collections;
    }
}
```

So now you can do

```
$customer = Customer::find(3);
$records = $customer->getRecords(); // result will be a collection
```

And inside your blade you can access them

```
@foreach ($records as $record) 
   {{ $record->stuffs }}
   {{ $records->product_data['other_stuffs'] }}
@endforeach
```

A collection can be filtered and sorted

```
$records->where('product_data.stuffs', 'abc')->sortBy('name');
```

The only problem here is the records id where Orange can have the same id as Green and Blue.
Best is to add new field into Orange Green and Blue
`$table->uuid('record_id')->nullable();`

Hope this can help you out.